# Laptop recommendations

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm picking out a laptop that will be exclusively used for ROS development. Does anyone have any recommendations for a specific model? I've got my eye on a Thinkpad T530, but I've heard of problems with Nvidia Optimus. I saw that a new driver has been released this month - how well does that work?

Edit: I'm going to be doing a lot of RViz/PCL stuff, so I need some horsepower

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61748/laptop-recommendations/) by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not clear what you specifically want to work on but there's already [a similar thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/52679/laptop-recommendation/#52682).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) on 2013-04-29**:
I'm curious as to how well the new Nvidia Linux driver (the one that fixes the Optimus issues) works with rviz and gazebo.